# GraphQL schema design for objects a part of whose values could change over the time

Tags: javascript, database-design, graphql

Assume that I have a dataset, which has a state like

```
company: {
  name: "Foobar Inc.",
  person: [{
    name: "Brah Brah",
    age: 47,
    location: [35.0000, 115.0000]
  }, {
    name: "Hoge Hoge",
    age: 24,
    location: [24.0000, 130.0000]
  }],
  budget: 12000
}
```

but the `age`, `location`, `budget` could change over the time.

When I design the data model for this structure in order to both distribute the state in real-time (e.g., for an web app) and persist the state from beginning to end (e.g., store the history of the company in the database for further analysis), there might be two ways to store the change.

1. Store the changes in each property
   This method will contain the changes in each property, making it an array which consists of the corresponding value and timestamp.

```
type Company @db(name: "company")  {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String!
  persons: [person!]! @relation (link: INLINE)
  budget: [NumericTS!]!
}

type Person @db(name: "person")  {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String!
  age: [NumericTS!]!
  location: [CoordinationTS!]!
}

type NumericTS @embedded {
  number: Integer!
  update: DateTime! @createdAt
}

type CoordinationTS @embedded {
  location: [Integer!]!
  update: DateTime! @createdAt
}
```

2. Store all the changes in `update` table
   This method, on the other hand, contains all the changes in an isolated table and consequently the properties will have only one value

```
type Company @db(name: "company")  {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String!
  persons: [person!]! @relation (link: INLINE)
  budget: Integer!
  updates: [Update!]!
}

type Person @db(name: "person")  {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String!
  age: Integer!
  location: [Integer!]!
}

type Update @embedded {
  target: String! // "e.g., person.age"
  integerUpdate: Integer // non-null allowed
  coordinationUpdate: [Integer]
  update: DateTime! @createdAt
}
```

Comparing two methods, it seems that the former method will be better if one wants to check the state at a specific time. For example, imagine that there is a seekbar with which one can skip time to time to see the state of the time. With the latter method, if one click "jump to the end", it is necessary to process all the changes to the end to complete the update.

On the other hand, if one needs to process the "time series" of the state, the latter way might be appropriate. Because the structure of the latter model is exactly same to the structure of a state, only one mutation given by the update table will be enough to derive the next state. The former method has timestamps in various properties, so it could be inefficient to find the exact times when an update occurs and derive the corresponding state one by one.

But I assume, still, with GraphQL queries it might be easy to find out the updates even if I go the former approach. Is this right? Given these all, which way is better to store this type of structure?

Comment: Based on the directives, I'm guessing the above are Prisma datamodels, but that's unclear from your question and/or tags. While Prisma and other, similar frameworks tightly couple the datatabase layer with the API, it's not strictly necessary to do so. That is, just because your tables model the data in a certain shape doesn't necessitate that your types also follow this shape. With regards to GraphQL itself, the storage layer is largely *irrelevant*.

Comment: Yes it is a prisma datamodel (I should have written that). Could you elaborate it a bit? I couldn't figure it out exactly.